# Mysql get count with php prepared

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want get count rows in my table. How can I do it?

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `books`");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
?>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? right now I don't see you printing anything, have you tried `var_dump($result);`?

Comment: with var_dump i got many info,i want only int count number

Comment: Well var_dump would probably include the int count number, along with other information that could help you figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($Count);
$stmt->fetch();

echo "Count: $Count";
```

Comment: Thank you very much Leo its ok.i want it.Thank you very much :)